# Change Capistrano strategy

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I want to change the default strategy that Capistrano uses to Copy. For this I have included the following line in the Capfile

```
set :strategy, Capistrano::Deploy::Strategy::Copy.new(self)
```

But it throws an exception

```
Capfile:17:in `load': uninitialized constant Capistrano::Deploy::Strategy::Copy (NameError)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is this?

```
set :deploy_via, :copy
```

refs: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L46

Comment: Updated reference link (for those playing at home: use commit hashes rather than branch names): https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/b84258a/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L246-249